# If $P(P(x)-1) = 1 + x^{36}$ then $P(2)=$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Is it possible to solve this problem?Can anyone give me some hints?

If $P(P(x)-1) = 1 + x^{36}$ then $P(2)=$

What I did so far.

$P(P(2) - 1) = 1+2^{36}$

$P(P(1) - 1) = 1+1 = 2 \Rightarrow P^{-1}(2) = P(1) - 1$

$P(P(0) - 1) = 1+0 = 1 \Rightarrow P^{-1}(1) = P(0) - 1$

$P(P(-1) - 1) = 1+1 = 2 \Rightarrow P(-1)=P(1)$

$P(P(-2) - 1) = 1+2^{36} \Rightarrow P(-2)=P(2)$

$P(x)=1+ \left\{ P^{-1}(x+1) \right\}^{36}$ and $P(2) = 1 + \left\{ P^{-1}(3) \right\}^{36}$

I don't see any connection from the expressions above.

Comment: Can you tell where you got this question from? Or some other context?

Comment: From the equation we can deduce that $\deg P=6$. Then $P(X)=1+x^6$ is a solution. Maybe you can prove it is unique?

Comment: Are we to assume that $P(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @AnkitSahu it came from local competition. The question is like that.

Comment: @lulu maybe. I am not really sure.

Comment: Well, the use of letter $P$ probably means that $P$ is a polynomial, I think this is a safe assumption here. Moreover, it's got to be a *real* polynomial, as over $\mathbb C$ there are additional solutions $P(x)=\epsilon x^6+1$ where $\epsilon$ is a $7$th root of unity. (And, perhaps other solutions as well???)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible Hint's: Write $$P(x)=g(x)+1$$ then we have $$g(g(x))=x^{36}$$
One of the possible guess is $g(x)=x^6$. Since the question is not clear, I will not proceed.